# Whats relation between nonlinear effects in fiber?

Tags: fiber-optics, non-linear-optics

I only know nonlinear effects occurs in fiber when power of propogating light is more than a "threshold".What other factors arises these **nonlinear** phenomenon?

and why is it called nonlinear? Which optical characteristics are nonlinear.

- Self-Phase Modulation (SPM)
- Cross-Phase Modulation (XPM)
- Four-WaveMixing (FWM)

Are these effect **independent** or **dependent**?

if they are dependent how is **relation between them**?

thanks for reply.

Comment: Are you asking what is non-linearity in general in physics ?

Comment: no,for example i want know when SPM increased ,XPM should decrease  or increase?

Comment: I suggest you start by learning about linear and nonlinear equations from a purely mathematical point of view, then try reading about interactions between photons and materials.  Only after that start to try to understand different kinds of nonlinear behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why they called nonlinear?

Nonlinear optical effects are called that because they happen when the dielectric polarization of a medium responds nonlinearly to an applied electric field. In a linear medium, the polarization is given by

$$\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_0\chi_e\mathbf{E}$$

Where $\mathbf{E}$ is the electric field vector, $\chi_e$ is the electric susceptibility of the material (which may be a tensor rather than a scalar in an anisotropic material), $\varepsilon_0$ is the electric permittivity of free space, and $\mathbf{P}$ is the resulting polarization vector.

In a nonlinear material we have instead

$$\mathbf{P}=\varepsilon_0\left(\chi^{(1)}\mathbf{E}+\chi^{(2)}\mathbf{E}^2+...\right)$$

Generally the high-order terms go to zero for small values of $\left|\mathbf{E}\right|$, so that the behavior is linear when the electric field is weak, and the nonlinear behavior only becomes significant when the electric field is strong.

> these effect is independent or dependent? if they are dependent how is relation between them?

Although I don't think there is any relationship between the different nonlinear effects (unless two effects happen to depend on the same $\chi^{(n)}$ term), they will all follow this pattern: not significant for weak fields and becoming stronger as the field strength increases. Which effects dominate in different materials will depend on which of the $\chi^{(n)}$ terms is relatively largest in a particular material, and whether the stimulus signals are provided to allow a particular effect.

Comment: @Haris, The effects OP asked about (SPM, XPM, FWM) result from the nonlinear polarization of the dielectric, as I described in my answer. They don't relate to dispersion.